# Debugging never resolving promises / async await

Tags: node.js, debugging, async-await, promise

On the project I'm working on, we sometimes have some await never resolving due to bad promises never resolving.

This is kind of really hard to find which await is causing the code to stop running and to find where node.js is stuck.

Here is a code illustration of the problem. Let's say "getRandomlyStuckedPromise" is a promise coming from an external library :

```
getRandomlyStuckedPromise = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.9) return;
  resolve(); // never get called some times
});

await getBadPromise();
await getBadPromise();
await getBadPromise();
await getBadPromise();
await getBadPromise();
await getBadPromise(); // Node.js stuck at one line ... how to know which one ?
await getBadPromise();
await getBadPromise();
```

If you have already met that kind of issue, do you know some tools in node.js or any technique to find on which await node.js is stuck ?

Comment: Move the `return` under the `resolve()`. return exists the current function therefore, yes, resolve is never called. TBH you don't need the return at all

Comment: That's just to illustrate the pb ... Please read above ;)

Comment: So what's the actual question? Why are your promises not resolving? We can't figure that out from the information you've provided. It could literally be 1,000s of things

Comment: Okay my question at the end is probably not well formulated ... I will rewrite it. I don't want to know the problem inside the promise (since it can come from a lib or anything else). I want to know on which "await" node.js is stuck. I will edit my question.

Comment: Well you should add some logging then and/or debug it yourself if you can re-create it

Comment: Adding logs around would solve the issue effectively. I'm working on a huge project (with puppeteer) which involve adding an await on each methods you call in this lib. It seems one of it get stucked ... but there is something like 50 await in the problematic function. And sadly the problem happens kind of randomly :/ That's why i'm searching for something a bit more efficient than console.log('Here i am').

Comment: Somewhere i've saw something like making kind of timeout promises with Promise.race : 
Promise.race(getBadPromise(), new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1e4)))
But doing this on every promises/await ... what a pity ! :D

Comment: @Poyoman It occurred to me later: if this is all Puppeteer, can't you use [`setDefaultNavigationTimeout` and `setDefaultTimeout`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md) to give you better error messages? Or pass a `timeout` parameter for any exceptions?

Comment: @JeffBowman i found the bug thanks to your proposition. I did a wrapper slightly different from yours, using error stack trace to find where is located the await. In fact i was suspecting puppeteer ... but it was an await from an other part of my code causing the issue. Really thank you for your time and solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wrap or log the promises one way or another. Luckily you can write a very compact wrapper. If you're awaiting several promises at once, you could arrange them as an array and then use `map` to wrap each one for passing into `Promise.all` or wherever you need them.

```js
(async () => {

const getBadPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.8) return;
  if (Math.random() > 0.8) reject(new Error("Promise failed on its own"));
  resolve();
});

/**
 * Logs the given promise with the given label.
 *
 * Will reject the promise after a timeout if it does not return.
 */
function wrap(label, promise) {
  const timeout = 1000;
  // Log promise creation.
  console.log(`Start (${label})`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Set up timeout handler to reject.
    const timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error(`Timeout (${label}, ${timeout})`));
    }, timeout);
    // Promisify value (in case it's a primitive). Once it resolves,
    // log it, clear the timeout, and pass the results out of the function.
    Promise.resolve(promise).finally(() => {
      console.log(`End (${label})`);
      clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
    }).then(resolve, reject);
  });
}

console.log("Start.");
await wrap("1", getBadPromise());
await wrap("2", getBadPromise());
await wrap("3", getBadPromise());
await wrap("4", getBadPromise());
await wrap("5", getBadPromise());
await wrap("6", getBadPromise());
await wrap("7", getBadPromise());
await wrap("8", getBadPromise());
await wrap("9", getBadPromise());
console.log("Done.");

})().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Nice suggestion Jeff ! :) It does the tricks and that's not too heavy. I gonna wait a bit if there is solutions involving a debugging tool. But this one solve my problem !

Answer (score 0):

Based on @JeffBowman proposition i made a slightly different wrapper =>

```
const withRejectTimeout = (promise, timeout = 120000 /* 2mn */) => {
  const timeoutError = new Error('Promise timeout');

  return Promise.race([
    promise,
    new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(timeoutError), timeout)),
  ]);
};

await withRejectTimeout(getBadPromise());
await withRejectTimeout(getBadPromise());
await withRejectTimeout(getBadPromise());
await withRejectTimeout(getBadPromise());
await withRejectTimeout(getBadPromise());
await withRejectTimeout(getBadPromise());
await withRejectTimeout(getBadPromise());
```

This use the error stack trace to help locate the await causing problem.